# IllegalBlocksizeException - How to use Base64 to solve

Tags: java, security, cryptography, aes

I am having some troubles with the following code - I seem to be getting an IllegalBlocksizeException and am unsure what it is that I maybe doing incorrectly here? Would it be possible to get some advice / pointers?

Thanks

```
    public class Encryption
    {
        private SecretKeyFactory factory;
        private SecretKey tmp;
        private SecretKey secret;
        private Cipher cipher;

        private byte[] iv;
        private byte[] cipherText;

        private final KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("somepassword".toCharArray(), SALT, 65536, 256);
        private static final byte[] SALT = {(byte)0xc3, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x71, (byte)0x1c, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0xc2, (byte)0xee, (byte)0x77};

        public Encryption()
        {
            try
            {
                factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
                tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
                secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
                iv = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String encrypt(String valueToEncrypt) throws Exception
        {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(valueToEncrypt.getBytes()));
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherText);
        }

        public String decrypt(String encryptedValueToDecrypt) throws Exception
        {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(new Base64().encode(encryptedValueToDecrypt.getBytes())));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception
        {
            Encryption manager = new Encryption();
            String encrypted = manager.encrypt("this is a string which i would like to encrypt");
            System.out.println(encrypted);
            String decrypted = manager.decrypt(encrypted);
            System.out.println(decrypted);
            System.out.println(encrypted.equals(decrypted));
        }
}
```

The exception is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at encrypt.Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.java:52)
    at encrypt.Encryption.main(Encryption.java:60)
```

Comment: I don't think base64 is the source of your issue, but could you add the stack trace to the question? (Or, at least, specify in which line you get the issue).

Comment: Hi Sergio - stack trace added

Answer (score 3):

The only approach to begin with the implementation of cryptographic algorithms, from the functional point of view (please keep in mind that a working code is not necessarily a secure one, and a lot of thought should come in that direction), is incremental: first try raw AES with a fixed key, then add the key generated by PBKDF2 and only later Base64. The latter is just an encoding tool and should be the easiest part of the process.

But let's take a look to the code:
1. The initialization seems fine, if your goal is to generate the key out of a password.
2. During the decryption, this line stands off:

```
 cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(valueToEncrypt.getBytes()));
```

valueToEncrypt is a readable string, but you're trying to decrypt it. Since it has only lowercase letters and spaces, it might not trigger an error, but you're trying to base64-decode something that hasn't been base64-encoded. It would make more sense to try:

```
cipherText = cipher.doFinal(valueToEncrypt.getBytes());
```

Then the *cipherText* can be base64-encoded.

For the decryption part, undo the operations in encryption in the reverse order. If you encrypted and then base64-encoded, then base64-decode first and then decrypt.

As a final recommendation: think modular. Encode in one line and encrypt in another, so if you want to remove or add a layer you just have to toggle the comments on one line.

Answer (score 2):

You have reversed the base-64 encoding and decoding operations. Base-64 takes raw bytes and makes them into printable text. You can encode the output of an encryption operation to make it printable. But then you will need to base‑64–decode that text before trying to decrypt it.

This part of your `decrypt()` method is causing the problem:

```
cipher.doFinal(new Base64().encode(encryptedValueToDecrypt.getBytes()))
```

That should be:

```
cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedValueToDecrypt.getBytes()))
```

Asking for "pointers" is pretty open-ended. The best pointer I can give you: don't write this code yourself. Choose a package that provides a higher-level API, selecting high-security algorithms and applying them according to best practices. You don't know what you are doing, and you won't be able to write secure code. But using a high quality, open source library might help you begin to learn more about encryption.

Comment: Having had a look about I will use the bouncy castle implementation of AES here http://www.mytechnotes.biz/2012/08/aes-256-symmetric-encryption-with.html - Thanks for your help

Comment: @Biscuit128 This site isn't really about recommending libraries, but I will also point you to [Apache Shiro's Cryptography](http://shiro.apache.org/cryptography-features.html) features. BouncyCastle is good in the sense that it is comprehensive and written by knowledgeable people, but it is large and low-level, making it inherently harder to use. On top of that, the documentation sucks. Apache Shiro is higher-level, usage is more guided, and easier to use.

Comment: @Biscuit128 the domain name has changed  
https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/08/aes-256-symmetric-encryption-with.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably should base64 decode `encryptedValueToDecrypt` before you decrypt it.